# Why I can't find Clear Local Search History on Google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow

The Google support said that it is in the Play Store at the Settings, but there isn't this option. [image]
I can find only these. I tried to delete all upgrades, and I found it at the 6.9.21 version, but not at the latest version.
I have Leagoo M8 with Android 6.0 (literally Freeme OS).